# Variable input to MATLAB function resets involuntarily inside while loop. How can I prevent it?

Tags: matlab, environment-variables

I have written a function which takes in an integer (int8) as one of the inputs (called iscool). The function runs a while loop and I insert an if-check inside it to break out of the loop. The if-check checks the value of the iscool variable as well and sets the value of imarch to 0 to get out of loop. So basically, the code is something like this.

```
% Code_snippet
  while (imarch == 1)
      <some procedures not modifying iscool>
      if ((iscool == 0) && (<other condition 1>) && (<other condition 2>))
           imarch = 0;
      elseif ((iscool == 1) && (<other condition 3>) && (<other condition 4>))
           imarch = 0;
      end
      disp (strcat('Cooling index is: ',num2str(iscool)));
  end
```

The output of the disp command in the first while-loop execution is 0 (which is the input), but it changes to 1 in the subsequent iteration and stays so after that. I have tried removing the if-elseif-end check and the value of iscool stays intact in that case, but I need to have the check in order to be able to get out of the loop. Any sort of help, particularly an insight into why the value might be changing would be great help. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect your `elseif` condition uses a single `=` by mistake, as in `iscool = 1` rather than as you have it in your sample code above.

Comment: MATLAB doesn't support expression-level assignments, @beaker, so I don't think that could be it. This does seem perplexing, though. user226928, are you positive that the procedures are not modifying iscool?

Comment: @SCFrench Hmm... works in Octave (but with a warning), but I believe that even in Matlab something like `if (notcool == 3) && (iscool = 1)` would work.

Comment: @beaker the elseif condition is not iscool = 1, I have checked that.  I have been able to work-around using a different termination condition which does not incorporate any checks on iscool and now, the code is working fine. However, it would be nice to figure out why the value of iscool was changing involuntarily.

Comment: @SCFrench I am positive that the procedures are not changing the value. In fact, after changing the of-elseif conditions, now my code is working fine (i.e. iscool is remaining the same through iterations).

Comment: Very perplexing. The only thing I can suggest at this point is that you use the debugger and step through the code until `iscool` changes.

Comment: I did that. Apparently, it changes once the second iteration of the while loop starts. I even printed out the value of `iscool` at different points in the loop to ensure this.
Anyway, I have managed a work-around wherein the termination condition for the loop does not involve a check on `iscool`